# Log user into particular Google account for demo

Tags: authentication, igoogle

My client created paid iGoogle apps but would like to demo them on an iGoogle page for which the user would need to log in to Google with a demo account.

On clicking a 'view demo' link, the user would need to be forced out of their own google account and logged into the demo one, then taken to iGoogle.

I have been playing around with posting auth forms to google but I'm guessing its not something they'll allow. Does anyone know if this is going to be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a link which will log someone out of there iGoogle by directing them to http://www.google.com/ig/logout?continue=http://www.google.com/ig.

I think creating an account for such purposes is against [Google Terms of Service](https://www.google.com/accounts/TOS?hl=en) though.

Also, there would be no means of locking the demo account, someone could very easily log into it and change all the account information if they wanted to be malicious.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the logout works fine.
I agree on all the other issues surrounding this.. it doesn't sound like such a great idea!

Comment: No problem, alternate idea might just be to have screenshots / video cast of the apps in action.